# Loading fragment from ListView's ItemClick listener

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have one Fragment Activity which  contains the listview. On click of the ListView's Items i want to load a fragment and close the Fragment activity.

I have tried to implement as below but getting the error of `FrameLayout` id where i am trying to load `Fragment`.

Logcat:

> ```
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0045 (com.zeal.peekaboo:id/fragmentswitcherframe) for fragment OtherProfileFragment{4a31cb00 #0 id=0x7f0a0045}
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>  09-03 16:49:57.321: E/AndroidRuntime(1740):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

**Listview ItemClick**

> ```
>    m_lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adptr, View view, int pos,
>                 long id) {
>             m_slistItemId = String.valueOf(m_lookArryList.get(pos)
>                     .getM_userId());
>             FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
>             FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
>             Fragment llf = new OtherProfileFragment();
>             ft.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcherframe, llf);
>             ft.commit();
>                             finish();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Please guide me for this. I am not able to understand what is going wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**"I am not able to understand what is going wrong?"**

If I understand this correct, then you load a Fragment in the layout of your FragmentActivity and close this Activity immediately after the commit() for the transaction with finish().

I don't know what you try to achieve but you will never see that Fragment. It will be destroyed when the Activity is destroyed, which happens because of the finish() call. This behavior is part of the Fragment [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). A Fragment can't exist alone, only with an Activity as host.

You get that error, because the [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) call for the Fragment transaction is async. Means that the Activity and the layout is closed through finish(), but the commit() of the transaction will still try to load the Fragment to the layout.

Edit:

If you wanna finish() the Activity, which holds the ListView, pass the results to another Activity via Intent. In this Activity build your View with the desired Fragment and hand it the results.

Maybe you wanna have a look at the [Master Detail Flow Pattern](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial), which is exactly for that use case. The Tutorial uses the standard template of Eclipse. You can get the idea out of it and modify it.

Comment: May be you are right but how can i load the fragment from the activity in which i have ListView and onItemClick of ListView I want to pass the result into another Fragment and finish the activity. Is there any way to achieve this ?